# Recycler view laggy scrolling when loading bitmap images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bitmap, android-glide

I'm showing lot of pdfs using recyclerview. I'm converting first page of a pdf into image and then showing it beside the pdf file. I'm using glide library for loading those bitmaps. But, recyclerview lags while scrolling. How to make the scrolling smooth?

Code for converting pdf to bitmap:-

```
public static Bitmap pdfToBitmap(File pdfFile) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
            final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
            if (pageCount > 0) {
                PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(0);
                int width = (int) (page.getWidth());
                int height = (int) (page.getHeight());
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
                page.close();
                renderer.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Code for loading the bitmap into imageview:

```
Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(bitmap)
                .into(viewHolder.pdfImg);
```

Comment: most of the items, it's because of the size of your images. try to resize them when load them by  ->     .apply(new RequestOptions().override(width, height))

Comment: can you please share you xml design code

Comment: @behrad I don't want to lower the quality of the images. Is there any other way?

Comment: @ShivanshuRaj before setting adapter, create a for loop of your main list. Now create a new list of your image from pdf first page. Now in a loop of your main list create a image and add it to image list. Now pass the images list in adapter and set image as per image list position. In adapter main list and images list both size will be same. Let me know if you didn't understand.

Comment: @ShivanshuRaj .  it does not reduce the quality of the image, it just fits it, for example, your image is 1000*1000 and your imageView can show just 300*300.  so you don't need to load main image